# Could not load NIB in bundle error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

I have an application that was initially working although I got a "could not find xxx.nib file" or something of that sort. This was because I deleted the .xib file from the project and xcode was still looking for it. The error annoyed me and so I fixed it by cleaning the project, resetting the simulator, and deleting all the cache files in ~/var/xcode/...
That fixed the error but now I am receiving 
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle

Comment: Is it possible that nib/xib was being referenced by the applications Info.plist? (i.e. under "Main nib file base name")?

Comment: Under that key it says "MainWindow"... is this normal or should I change it.

Comment: Changing it to a bunch of other classes, xibs, did nothing

Answer (score 1):

try check and remove line with your xib in list of the Xcode project's Build Phase (may be red color):

[image]

Comment: I've tried this before and the reference to the .xib and its respective header and source are already removed.